# Bypass FTP,RemoteLogin,SMTP,TELNET through Squid3 proxy server which is installed on ubuntu 14.04.1

Tags: squid

Hi i have installed squid3 proxy server & the server is located between the switch & router all the traffic flows through squid3 server i am not able to:

1.Access FTP using filezilla software

2.Not able to update the mails as i am using thunderbird & microsoft outlook.

3.Not able to take remote of server outside the network using putty & Remote Desktop connection (Microsofts inbuilt tool)
4.Not able to send skype messages outside the network

I am able to

1.Browse http & https
2.Generate logs

I am not so familar with squid & iptables So please help me

I have not modified squid.conf file i have only entered the Network details & uncommented net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

which is present in /etc/sysctl.conf file